# ImageButtons aren't taking attributes from theme styles

Tags: java, android, android-layout

My `ImageButton`s don't seem to be affected by the parameters set out in the style document, however other `Button`s are when I define their style in the exact same way.

This is a condensed version of my styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Button</item>
    <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/ImageButton</item>
</style>

<style name="Button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@color/icons</item>
</style>

<style name="ImageButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.ImageButton">
    <item name="android:background">@color/icons</item>
</style>
```

When using these styles (I've tried it with other items however none seem to work), normal `Button`s will take the color of `@color/icons`, however `ImageButton`s don't. They also remain unaffected when their styles are set individually with `style="@style/ImageButton"`, however if I set the background directly with `android:background="@color/icons"` on each button it *does* have an affect.

Answer (score 0):

Use

> style="@style/ImageButton"

in your button body like:`

```
<Button
            style="@style/button_theme"
            android:text="Sign In" 
            android:id="@+id/id" />`
```

this is the button style

```
<style name="button_theme">
<item name="android:background">@drawable/button_shape</item>
<!--<item name="android:padding">5dp</item>-->

<item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>

<item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
```

Comment: As I said in my question, this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
OR you can use these styles in your theme like you shown above
```

just add this line
:-

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Button</item>
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/Button</item>
    <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/ImageButton</item>
</style>

<style name="Button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@color/icons</item>
</style>

<style name="ImageButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.ImageButton">
    <item name="android:background">@color/icons</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Same for the imageButtonStyle

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix the problem, the issue is it's working for normal buttons but strangely not for imageButtons, I did try it without the `android:` for imageButton too but it had no affect.